# definition of exchange lemma

Tags: vector-spaces

I want to understand basic of  exchange lemma,which is expressed like this:

> Theorem 1.2 (The Exchange Lemma) Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$. Suppose
>   that the vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly independent, and that the vectors $w_1,...,w_m$
>   are linearly independent, where $m > n$. Then we can ﬁnd a number i with $1 \le i \le m$
>   such that the vectors $v_1,...,v_n,w_i$ are linearly independent.

I did not understand one thing, first we see that we have two set of independent vectors, if i add  some additional vector from one set  to another set, why we got again independent vector set? Does not make it set to dependent?

Also i will try to consider such kind of thing, we know that  vector are independent if

$c_1*v_1+c_2*v_2+...+c_n*v_n=0$ if  $c_1=c_2=...c_n=0$

For another vector we can express like this way, now if i add some vector for example $w_2$, maybe because it's factor like $b_2*w_2$, or in this case because $b_2=0$ from the definition of linear independence of $w_i$ vectors, we don't change anything right? Then maybe we can say strictly that whenever we add any vector from one independent set to another, we get independent set again, just  this lemma says we can find, but in fact it is always right? Please help me to clarify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you suggest is not true in general; here’s a counterexample.

The set $\{\langle 1,0,0\rangle,\langle 0,1,0\rangle\}$ is linearly independent in $\Bbb R^3$, and so is the set $\{\langle 0,0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1,0\rangle\}$, but if you add $\langle 1,1,0\rangle$ to the first set, you get $\{\langle 1,0,0\rangle,\langle 0,1,0\rangle,\langle 1,1,0\rangle\}$, which is **not** linearly independent:

$$1\cdot\langle 1,0,0\rangle+1\cdot\langle 0,1,0\rangle-1\cdot\langle 1,1,0\rangle=\langle 0,0,0\rangle\;,$$

and the coefficients $1,1$, and $-1$ are certainly not all $0$.

Comment: thanks very much,i see now,i have considered  not vector itself,but vector multiplied by zero coefficient

Comment: @dato: You’re welcome.

Comment: btw   @Brain M.Scott i think coefficient should be $2,2,-2$

Comment: @dato: Actually, I meant to have $1,1$, and $-1$. But you’re right that I made a silly computational error; thanks for catching it.

Comment: you are welcome,thanks for help